# Permissions not inheriting to files and folders in Linux mint

Tags: linux, file-permissions, access-control-list

We are using Linux mint with ext4 file system mounted with acl option, I want to set a folder such that anything created within it directories or files inherit default permissions and group = 775, I have applied setfacl with options (-R -d -m ugo:rwx)i also tried changing user umask 0002 but still files being created as 644 can someone please help me with this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior of Linux Mint and some users consider it as a bug.

As a workaround, you can create a new script:

```
echo "umask 002" > /etc/profile.d/umask.sh
```

This will set the umask when you login.

Edit #1:

Can you please check [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52161/how-to-test-for-possible-conflicts-while-using-alias-in-bashrc/52166#52166)? I'd try and run that code:

```
bash -x -l -i -c 'exit' 2>&1 | grep ' umask '
```

to verify that umask is configured correctly.

Comment: Thanks Itai, interesting but the umask is already set to 0002 when i run umask cmd it tells 0002, so you think its not being applied...

Comment: Sure will run that in the after hours as i don't want any interruption to server thanks.

Comment: The command will not interrupt the server in any way, it’s safe.

Comment: I ran above command but I just recalled that I have already created a bashrc for umask and it didn't change anything for me so I removed it again, I have also added umask to /etc/profile.d that didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

While not an exact duplicate your question seems very similar to this one :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/642236/how-to-make-the-newly-created-files-inherit-the-directorys-permissions

Hopefully the answer there is applicable to your problem also, let me know

Comment: Sean i have already applied your suggestions but still no no manager@Sesame-mint ~/Desktop/Sesame2 $ umask
0002
manager@Sesame-mint ~/Desktop/Sesame2 $ getfacl DB-3-10
# file: DB-3-10
# owner: manager
# group: manager
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:manager:rwx
group::rwx
group:manager:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:manager:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:manager:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx

after all above the files are still being created 644

-rw-r--r--+ 1 manager manager 1669067837 Feb 10 19:27 DB-3-101518308853.dat